# Reaction rate and temperature

Tags: temperature

I recall being told that for a given reaction, every 10 degree rise in temperature the reaction rate approximately doubles. Is this true?

Comment: It is a simple question, a simple answer would suffice.

Comment: Is the purpose of this forum to give answers that are for the cogniscenti or the questioners?